# keep iphone led open in Multitasking

Tags: iphone, multitasking, led

Hi I have find a way to switch on and off the led flashlight of iphone 4 and also to have a strobe effect but I am trying to keep it lit when the app goes to background and I cant. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as know you cant do this. When the app goes to the background, apple allows only limited amount to resources to your app & allows your app limited freedom.

For example, you can play audio when your app is in background. You can have network access (for any downloads etc.) when your app is in background. So don't think its possible to keep LED lit when the app goes to background.

Correct me if i am wrong or would love to know how you eventually solved this problem..